# postgresql - how to show null values in the aggregated and joined tables output?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
select * from tokens;
 id |      datefield      | category | amount 
----+---------------------+----------+--------
  1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |        1 |      3
  4 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |        1 |      3
  2 | 2019-01-15 00:00:00 |        2 |      1
  5 | 2019-01-25 00:00:00 |        3 |      2
  3 | 2019-02-17 00:00:00 |        2 |      1
  6 | 2019-03-16 00:00:00 |        1 |      5
  7 | 2019-03-11 00:00:00 |        3 |      6

select * from category;
 id |   name    
----+-----------
  1 | fiction
  2 | sports
  3 | news
```

Now I want to join these tables and show total amounts per category per month in a table as follows:

```
  name   | sum | monthfield 
---------+--------+------------
 fiction |   3    | 2019-01
 sports  |   1    | 2019-01
 news    |   2    | 2019-01
 fiction |   3    | 2019-02
 sports  |   1    | 2019-02
 news    |   NULL | 2019-02
 fiction |   5    | 2019-03
 sports  |   NULL | 2019-03
 news    |   6    | 2019-03
```

I have written the following query **however I can not get the rows with the NULL value** as show in the above desired output:

```
select
  c.name, sum(t.amount), to_char(t.datefield, 'YYYY-MM') as monthfield
from
  category c
FULL OUTER JOIN
  tokens t on c.id = t.category
group by
  (c.name, c.id, monthfield)
order by
  (to_char(t.datefield, 'YYYY-MM'),c.id)
  ;

  name   | sum | monthfield 
---------+-----+------------
 fiction |   3 | 2019-01
 sports  |   1 | 2019-01
 news    |   2 | 2019-01
 fiction |   3 | 2019-02
 sports  |   1 | 2019-02
 fiction |   5 | 2019-03
 news    |   6 | 2019-03
```

I will appreciate if you can help me to fix the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `tokens` has at least one value per month, you can do:

```
select 
    c.name,
    sum(t.amount) sum_amount,
    to_char(m.monthfield, 'yyyy-mm') monthfield
from 
    category c
    cross join (select distinct date_trunc('month', datefield) monthfield from tokens) m
    left join tokens t
        on t.category = c.id
        and t.datefield >= m.monthfield
        and t.datefield < m.monthfield+ interval '1 month'
group by c.id, c.name, to_char(m.monthfield, 'yyyy-mm')
order by monthfield, c.id
```

The query generates a cartesian product between the `category` table and all available months in `tokens`. Then, table `tokens` is brought in with a `left join` on the category and date range. Finally, data is aggregated by category and month.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed570a09308998c143d91fbf5ebfebfd)**:

```
name    | sum_amount | monthfield
:------ | ---------: | :---------
fiction |          3 | 2019-01   
sports  |          1 | 2019-01   
news    |          2 | 2019-01   
fiction |          3 | 2019-02   
sports  |          1 | 2019-02   
news    |       null | 2019-02   
fiction |          5 | 2019-03   
sports  |       null | 2019-03   
news    |          6 | 2019-03
```